# Remove all HTML tags from a string using Codename One

Tags: codenameone

How do i remove all html tags from a string using Codename One. See below sample spring.

```html
<p><b>Introduction to the Course</b><br /></p><p>Dear learner, welcome to the <span style=\"font-size:11pt;font-family:'Franklin Gothic Book', 'sans-serif';\" lang=\"en-gb\" xml:lang=\"en-gb\">Effective Management and Control of Asthma training programme.</span> The<span style=\"font-size:11pt;font-family:'Franklin Gothic Book', 'sans-serif';\" lang=\"en-gb\" xml:lang=\"en-gb\"> training programme</span> </p><p>Happy learning!<br /></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a suitable `com.codename1.util.regex.RE` object and `subst`itute a blank string for the tags.

Comment: You could also use the `XMLParser` class and then walk over the tree and get all text elements then concatenate them to a String. `XMLParser` works fine with HTML/SGML

Comment: @ShaiAlmog kindly provide a sample code using above Example, you co-founded Codename One i believe you can help on this.

Comment: I did. There are examples within the JavaDocs and developer guide for working with XMLParser

Comment: Okay, i will check it out. Did you guys do away with j2me build? What happens now if we want the app in the feature phones?